# Copy all module from Old workbook to New Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy all module from old workbook to new one.
ฺBefore that, I create module to select worksheet from my old workbook and save as new workbook.
Example Code :

```
Sub Savesheet()
    Sheet1.Select
    Sheet2.Select False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy
    ChDir "C:\Users\Desktop"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= New_workbook, _
        FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

but new workbook have worksheet only. I want to copy all module to new workbook too

I try to use record macro and move module to new file manually but It doesn't show any code.

Advice me please

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Easiest way would be to make a copy of the old workbook using `SaveCopyAs`, open the new file and remove the unwanted sheets. Copying modules would need disabled security settings.

Comment: Do not copy sheets. Just save the workbook as XLSM **with a different name** and then remove any unwated sheets. Your original workbook will not suffer any changes and your new workbook will have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the VB Editor with ALT-F11.
It lets us select individual modules and export them as separate files.

It seems someone's already written the code to do it.
See if the code at the bottom of the link is what you need... ?

https://forum.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/109813-export-all-modules-at-once-to-a-folder-on-disk/

At the very bottom.  He has two codes:
one starts with:
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String) As Boolean

The other:
Sub ExportMacros()
SaveModuleNames.SaveModuleNames
...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).